# Как поместить spring приложение в docker контейнер так, чтобы при изменении файлов на локальной машине эти изменения автоматически применялись в

Tags: java, docker, spring-boot, maven

Мне необходимо поместить spring boot приложение в docker контейнер, при этом чтобы не приходилось каждый раз собирать новый .jar файл (при изменении незначительной части кода будет неоправданно долго ожидать пока он соберётся). Недавно перешёл на Java, поэтому скорее всего не совсем правильно понимаю принцип сборки и запуска, хотелось бы понять направление для решения этого вопроса

Answer (score 0):

Здесь не имеет значение докер контейнер или нет, ваша проблема - в долгой пересборке `jar` файла при незначительных изменениях кода.

Для решения есть два пути - первое это настроить автоматическую сборку continious integration - которая при отправке кода в репозиторий будет сама собирать `jar` и `docker` образ. Второе - это разделить сове приложение на модули, у каждого модуля должна быть ограниченная причина для изменнеия (принцип S в SOLID), то есть если у вас есть автомобили и их владельцы - нам не надо пересобирать классы с автомобилями, при изменении владельца - потому их стоит разделить на разные модули и пересобирать только нужную часть